# CVS in Eclipse: what the are the numbers next to all my source files

Tags: eclipse, cvs

on right side of all my source files in Eclipse (I just enabled CVS).. it shows "1.1"... i don't recognize this # as being a version # of my program, so what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the number shown is the revision of the file

more info here: http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/cvs/revisions.html